# Symfony bundle parent services.yml ignored

Tags: symfony

I have 2 bundle MyBundle1 and MyBundle2 , MyBundle2 inherits MyBundle1.

In /app/config/services.yml i have:

`imports:
  - resource: '@MyBundle1/Resources/config/services.yml'
  - resource: '@MyBundle2/Resources/config/services.yml'`

The problem is that '@MyBundle2/Resources/config/services.yml' will be considered as '@MyBundle1/Resources/config/services.yml' because it inherits it, so override its files.

My question is: How can I access to the real '@MyBundle2/Resources/config/services.yml', not the one rewritten ?

Thanks

Comment: You could try different filenames (eg. `_services.yml` in Bundle2).

Comment: @ccKep it will work but not as proper/nice/standard as i would like

Comment: Could try to import `@MyBundle1/Resources/config/services.yml` from within `@MyBundle2/Resources/config/services.yml`

Comment: Also: Providing the full path in your `app/config/services.yml` should work, overriding only works with the `@` syntax as explained in the [cookbook](http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/inheritance.html#overriding-resources-templates-routing-etc) (second to last info box)

Comment: @ccKep the last one did work, but i think i will change the filename to _services as you mentionned, because i can't bear the "../../src/" in the import. It seems there is a DependencyInjection/Configuration to force the loading of files, but I will accept your answer with the solution _services.yml if you write it ;) Wanted the simpliest and nicest solution

Comment: `"%kernel.root_dir%/../src/` is an alternative as well. Will compile all those in an answer shortly.

Comment: @ccKep no because if I want my modules to be put in the vendor folder (by creating composer.json for those bundles, and added in packagist), it wont work anymore.

Comment: @ccKep write an answer with the content of the comments, in order to close the question ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Symfony cookbook](http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/inheritance.html#overriding-resources-templates-routing-etc) explains that Bundles override their parent Bundles resource files when

1. they're in the same location inside the bundle
2. They've been imported using the `@MyBundle/...../services.yml` (the @-part) syntax.

In order to have your Bundle **not** override your parent Bundles services you can use a different filename (eg. `_services.yml`) or refer to it using the full path in your config.